# How to get fourier series of 8-bit character to be transmitted?

Tags: signal, fourier, transmission

I have been reading this in a book, but can't understand how he used the 8-bit in fourier series equation to get the result below.

The transmission of the ASCII character ‘‘b’’ encoded in an 8-bit byte. The bit pattern that is to be transmitted is 01100010. The Fourier analysis of this signal yields the coefficients:

an =(1/πn)[cos(πn/4) − cos(3πn/4) + cos(6πn/4) − cos(7πn/4)]

bn = (1/πn)[sin(3πn/4) − sin(πn/4) + sin(7πn/4) − sin(6πn/4)]

c = 3/4

[image: Signal]

I mean if I want to transmit letter 'a' for example, in ASCII Code it's 97 and in 8-bit is 0110 0001. How can I get its Fourier equation? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To be able to answer this, you'll have to define what the signal looks like before and after the given bit-train. Is it high at t < 0 and t > 7? (where t is a bit-time). Is it low? Is your bit train repeating itself? ...

Comment: @jippie I added the image above, plz take a look.

Comment: @AliZahr - it seems simple enough - the waveform is presumed to repeat and the waveform (the series of 1s and 0s) is multiplied by the equivalent "fundamental" of the repeating pattern (sin and cos) to get two numbers which vectorially add together - this is repeated at the "fundamental" x2 then x3 etc..

Comment: What Andy aka said. You have to assume that the bit pattern is repeated forever.. so you are not sending b, but bbbbbbbbbbb...

Comment: This question has been answered on math.SE [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928890/how-to-get-fourier-series-of-8-bit-character-to-be-transmitted/930008#930008).